# How to create clickable ListView and open JSON data onClick on each new page?

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, listview

I have created a clickable ListView with a TextView on the new page. I would like to display JSON data in this TextView, and I want the JSON data to be retrieved by clicking the ListView item i.e. opening the new page. Is this possible?

Below you will find the code I have so far. The ListView is clickable and functions correctly, but the JSON code does not.

If you know the solution to my problem, you're a superstar! Thank you in advance.

### **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] names = {
            "A",
            "B"
    };

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view, names);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Searching " + names[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("names", names[position]);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    JSONArray reader = new JSONArray(readJSONFromAsset());
                    ListView tvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                    TextView tvContext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
                    String codeArray = tvData.getAdapter().toString();

                    for (int x = 0; x < reader.length(); x++) {
                        JSONObject Array = reader.getJSONObject(x);
                        String data = Array.getString("data");
                        String context = Array.getString("context");
                        if (data.equals(codeArray)) {
                            tvContext.setText(context);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public String readJSONFromAsset() {
                String json = null;
                try {
                    InputStream is = getAssets().open("data.json");
                    int size = is.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    is.read(buffer);
                    is.close();
                    json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
                return json;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

### **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### **DetailActivity.java**

```
package com.example.steen.array;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail);

        textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("names"));
    }
}
```

### **activity_detail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### **list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</TextView>
```

### **data.json**

```
[
  {
    "data": "A",
    "context": "(A) if you see this, JSON is working"
  },
  {
    "data": "B",
    "context": "(B) if you see this, JSON is working"
  }
]
```

Comment: can you log and tell me what you get in String "Data" and context

Comment: if you are getting the position of the that list, you can then get the same position in the jsonarray to display. thats one way.

Comment: @Ashish activity_main shows a ListView: "A", "B". If I click on either, I get a new page which only states "A" or "B", depending on which page I open.

Comment: @soldforapp "if you are getting the position of the that list, you can then get the same position in the jsonarray to display. thats one way." I'm afraid I don't understand how to do that.

Comment: if you click on the list item, you can get the position like int pos = listView.getItemAtPosition(position); you can now pass that with your intent. From there, parse through your json array and the get jsonobject at that position. its one way.

Comment: @soldforapp I see, where would that go? In other words, what changes would I have to make?

Comment: that goes where you click the item in the list.

Comment: @soldforapp Could you show me please? :)

Comment: inside of your mainactivity, where your setOnItemClickListener method is.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm too much of a coding noob to figure that out on my own...

Comment: Yes I did, but I still wouldn't say I'm very good. And I tried to add int pos = listView.getItemAtPosition(position); to the setOnItemClickListener, but that did not work. That's why I asked for a more concrete example.

Comment: what didnt work? did you print it out to see if it got the positiaon of the click?